# Apache em diferentes diferentes linguagens de Programação

Tags: php, java, apache

Qual a diferença entre o servidor Apache para PHP (Wan) e o Web Container Apache TomCat?

Comment: o apache he o processador web ele vai pegar sua requisição e processar para ver o q fazer com ela. o php e o tomcat serve para processar a linguagem php e java e devolver a instrução executada ao apache para que ele exiba no seu navegador as informações. o apache sozinho nao sabe o q fazer ele so sabe exibir, ele le e retorna mais nada , quem executa pensa resolve as coisas são os processadores de linguagem no caso o php e o tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Apache Tomcat é uma versão open source do servlet (classe) para desenvolvimento Web com Java ([aqui](http://tomcat.apache.org/)). O Apache HTTP tem um módulo que habilita seu funcionamento com o PHP ([aqui](https://httpd.apache.org/)). Acredito que a versão à qual você se refere (Apache Wan) seja o [WAMP SERVER](http://www.wampserver.com/en/), que é um tudo-em-um com o serviço WEB, PHP, MySQL, etc (para windows).